# Remove padding from columns in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

**Problem:**

Remove padding/margin to the right and left of `col-md-*` in Bootstrap 3.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>OntoExplorer<span style="color:#b92429">.</span></h2>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h3>Dimensions</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="widget-content" id="">
                <div id='jqxWidget'>
                    <div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:20px;" id="listBoxA"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;" id="listBoxB"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h3>Results</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="widget-content">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 362px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**Desired output:**

Currently this code adds padding/margin to the right and left of the two columns. I am wondering what am I missing in order to remove this extra space on the sides?

**Notice:**

If I remove `col-md-4` then both columns expand to 100% but I want them to be next to each other.

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 use ```pl-0 pr-0``` i.e. ```<div class="col-7 pl-0 pr-0">```

Comment: Even shorter, `px-0`, which includes both left and right.

Comment: For BS 5 I use .g-0 or .mx-0 on .row

Comment: @Théophile thank you for that. `pl-0 pr-0` didn't work for me on Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 502, accepted):

You'd normally use [`.row`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1416) to wrap two columns, not `.col-md-12` - that's a column encasing another column. Afterall, [`.row`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1416) doesn't have the extra margins and padding that a `col-md-12` would bring and also discounts the space that a column would introduce with negative left & right margins.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>OntoExplorer<span style="color:#b92429">.</span></h2>

        <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <h3>Dimensions</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <h3>Results</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you *really* wanted to remove the padding/margins, add a class to filter out the margins/paddings for each child column.

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Is adding .without-padding to the container class even necessary? I'd say adding .nopadding to the .col-md-8 div with the CSS code you provided is sufficient.

Comment: I usually create 3 extra classes in my custom CSS namely, `.padding-0` that sets the left and right padding (only) to 0; `.padding-sm` that sets padding to 2px and `.padding-md` that sets the padding to 5px. The usual padding is 15px (unless customized), so these extra classes are sufficient.

Comment: by the way [.row](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1416) moved it's new line

Comment: The usual padding is customized in variables.less
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;

Comment: is there any predefined bootstrap to remove padding or creating a class is only solution

Comment: For me adding the class `no-gutter` removed the padding, margin from the cells

Comment: Old, but thought I'd at that this also wipes out your offsets it seems.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Yes, as of Bootstrap 3.4.0, there is. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776151/1128737).

Answer (score 227):

**Bootstrap 5** has added [vertical and horizontal gutter classses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/)

**Bootstrap 4** has added [.no-gutters class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters).

**Bootstrap 3.4** has added [.row-no-gutters class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters)

**Bootstrap 3**: I always add this style to my Bootstrap LESS / SASS:

```
.row-no-padding {
  [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Then in the HTML you can write:

```
<div class="row row-no-padding">
```

If you want to only target the child columns you can use the child selector (Thanks John Wu).

```
.row-no-padding > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

You may also want to remove padding only for certain device sizes (SASS example):

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-max) {
  .row-sm-no-padding {
    [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 0 !important;
      padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

You can remove the max-width part of the media query if you want it to support small devices upwards.

Comment: how to add this in SASS?

Comment: This is plain CSS apart from the nesting (which is also in SASS), so it should work the same.

Comment: Works perfectly in a responsive environment.

Comment: I suggest using direct child selector to improve performance. Use `& >[class*="col-"]` instead.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Then you can be more specific about which rows you don't want padding on, which will stop automatically include all descendants. My solution was just to cover the OP's case where he has columns nested in columns.

Comment: @JohnWu that also prevents nested rows from inheriting the style, which caused me a bit of trouble. thanks!

Comment: You really should use `[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"] {...}` instead so you don't accidentally target classes named `foocol-` for example. This will target elements that have that class name at the *start* or have it as a secondary class as well without targeting where the string is found as part of another class name.

Comment: Holy smokes! I just spent hours battling with what I thought was an iOS viewport bug because my iPhone 6 would sometimes (but inconsistently) autozoom in on my webpage. After removing the col padding, I think the autozoom works appropriately! Thanks!

Comment: how to add/remove padding only for sm and md screens and not on xs and lg screens ? Please suggest..

Comment: Hi @Shivam, I've added an example above for removing padding for small devices only in SASS. You can adapt this to different sizes for your needs.

Answer (score 46):

Reducing just the padding on the columns won't make the trick, as you will extend the width of the page, making it uneven with the rest of your page, say navbar. You need to equally reduce the negative margin on the row. Taking @martinedwards' LESS example:

```
.row-no-padding {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is only a problem when your row isn't in a container or another column. The negative margins just offset the padding from those elements

Comment: I needed `!important` for both of the margins to make this work

Answer (score 34):

Hereafter only available at Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="p-0 m-0">
</div>
```

*note: .p-0 and .m-0 already added bootstrap.css*

Answer (score 22):

Specifically for SASS mixin:

```
@mixin no-padding($side) {
    @if $side == 'all' {
        .no-padding {
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    } @else {
        .no-padding-#{$side} {
            padding-#{$side}: 0 !important;
        }
    }
}

@include no-padding("left");
@include no-padding("right");
@include no-padding("top");
@include no-padding("bottom");
@include no-padding("all");
```

Then in HTML, you can use

```
.no-padding-left
.no-padding-right
.no-padding-bottom
.no-padding-top
.no-padding - to remove padding from all sides
```

Sure, you can @include only those declarations, which you need.

Comment: Im trying to use this mixin (thanks for that) in this situation and the padding it´s not working.

`.banners-home {
  @include make-row();
  .banner-comprar,.banner-pq{
    @include no-padding("all");
    @include make-xs-column(6);
    @include make-sm-column(6);
    @include make-md-column(6);
    @include make-lg-column(6);
  }
  .banner-simulador{
    @include no-padding("all");
    @include make-xs-column(12);
    @include make-sm-column(12);
    @include make-md-column(12);
    @include make-lg-column(12);
  }
}`

Comment: I figure out what's wrong. I need create another mixin for this solution works. Btw, thanks for the SASS mixin :)

Comment: I just create this `@mixin nopadding{
  padding:0!important;
}` in my `_mixin.scss`  and then add `@include nopadding;` to the code above. :)

Answer (score 19):

Simply add `no-padding` which is in-built class in Bootstrap 3

Comment: Works for me when adding to a column. This should be used when using nested columns to avoid multiple padding.

Comment: Also, one can add `no-gutter` class to the parent `.row`.

Comment: @ArtBIT I think you need to code `no-gutters` as per https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#no-gutters. It's not inbuilt.

Answer (score 12):

**Bootstrap 4** has a native class to do this : add the class `.no-gutters` to the parent `.row`

Answer (score 10):

Another solution, feasible only if you compile bootstrap from its LESS sources, is to redefine the variable which sets the padding for the columns.

You will find the variable in the `variables.less` file: it's called `@grid-gutter-width`.

It's described like this in the sources:

```
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
```

Set this to 0, compile `bootstrap.less`, and include the resulting `bootstrap.css`. You are done. It can be an alternative to defining an additional rule, if you are already using bootstrap sources like I am.

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 4 has the class .no-gutters that you can add to the row element.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            [YOUR CONTENT HERE]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap 3, since version [3.4.0](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/12/13/bootstrap-3-4-0/), has an official way of removing the padding: the class `row-no-gutters`.

Example from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters):

```
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[class*="col-"]
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked perfectly for me. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204586/1087811) I was able to create something that works for me. Here I am also using a media query to limit this to small screens only.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .container-fluid {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove spacing from b/w columns using bootstrap 3.7.7 or less.

> .no-gutter is a custom class that you can add to your row DIVs

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
        padding-right:0;
        padding-left:0;
    }
```

Comment: This worked and didn't require LESS or SASS. I did notice that I had to add the container class to my row, however, as well as apply this extra styling: `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: Devs will need to realize with this that once this is done, they need to create a DIV inside the column and apply margin to that in order to create their own gutter sizes.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2>OntoExplorer<span style="color:#b92429">.</span></h2>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="widget row">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <h3>Dimensions</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="widget-content" id="">
            <div id='jqxWidget'>
                <div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:20px;" id="listBoxA"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;" id="listBoxB"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="widget row">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <h3>Results</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="widget-content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 362px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add a class of row to the div inside the col-md-4 and the row's -15px margin will balance out the gutter from the columns.  Good explanation [here](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) about gutters and rows in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's easier to just use

```
margin:-30px;
```

to override the original value set by bootstrap.

I've tried

```
margin: 0px -30px 0px -30px;
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your columns in a .row and add to that div a class called "no-gutter"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <h2>OntoExplorer<span style="color:#b92429">.</span></h2>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h3>Dimensions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h3>Results</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then paste below contents to your CSS file

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove/customize Bootstrap Gutter with css
reference: http://arnique.net/web-design/58/a-quick-guide-to-changing-bootstraps-gutter-width/

```css
/* remove */
.gutter-0.row {
  margin-right: -0px;
  margin-left: -0px;
}
.gutter-0 > [class^="col-"], .gutter-0 > [class^=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

/* customize */
.gutter-6.row {
  margin-right: -3px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.gutter-6 > [class^="col-"], .gutter-6 > [class^=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row gutter-6">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img width="100%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>more</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img width="100%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>more</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img width="100%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>more</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img width="100%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>more</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class for removing margin and can apply to the element where you want to remove extra margin:

```
.margL0 { margin-left:0 !important }
```

**!important** : it will help you to remove the default margin or overwrite the current margin value

and apply to that div from in which you want to remove the margin from left side

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.col-md-12{
 padding-left:0px !important;
padding-right:0px !important;
}
.col-md-8{
padding-left:0px !important;
padding-right:0px !important;
}
.col-md-4{
padding-left:0px !important;
padding-right:0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation with your answer.

Comment: provide these codes before or after <head> tag so that this will override those class properties in that page

Answer (score 0):

**You can create Less Mixins using bootstrap for manage margins and paddings of your columns like,**

http://mohandere.work/less-mixins-for-margin-and-padding-with-bootstrap-3/

**Usage:**

```
xs-padding-lr-15px//left right both
xs-padding-l-15px 
xs-padding-r-15px
```

Similarly for setting margin/padding  zero you can use,

```
xs-padding-lr-0px
xs-padding-l-0px
xs-padding-r-0px
```

Comment: It seems that essantial informations are on then linked page. This is not the way of SO. Put essential information in your answer!

Comment: Or people could just use the accepted answer with 159 upvotes and no downvotes, that's been here for two years. Or one of the several other answers with over ten upvotes. You'll have to try harder to earn a place on this page against that competition.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on [Vitaliy Silin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25052264/759452). Covering not only cases where we do not want padding at all, but also cases where we have standard size paddings.

[See the live conversion of this code to CSS on sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a00fd6c009c09458439d)

```
@mixin padding($side, $size) {
    $padding-size : 0;
    @if $size == 'xs' { $padding-size : 5px; }
    @else if $size == 's' { $padding-size : 10px; }
    @else if $size == 'm' { $padding-size : 15px; }
    @else if $size == 'l' { $padding-size : 20px; }

    @if $side == 'all' {
        .padding--#{$size} {
            padding: $padding-size !important;
        }
    } @else {
        .padding-#{$side}--#{$size} {
            padding-#{$side}: $padding-size !important;
        }
    }
}

$sides-list: all top right bottom left;
$sizes-list: none xs s m l;
@each $current-side in $sides-list {
  @each $current-size in $sizes-list {
    @include padding($current-side,$current-size);
  }
}
```

This then outputs:

```
.padding--none {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.padding--xs {
  padding: 5px !important;
}

.padding--s {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.padding--m {
  padding: 15px !important;
}

.padding--l {
  padding: 20px !important;
}

.padding-top--none {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.padding-top--xs {
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.padding-top--s {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.padding-top--m {
  padding-top: 15px !important;
}

.padding-top--l {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
}

.padding-right--none {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.padding-right--xs {
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}

.padding-right--s {
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}

.padding-right--m {
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}

.padding-right--l {
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}

.padding-bottom--none {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.padding-bottom--xs {
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.padding-bottom--s {
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.padding-bottom--m {
  padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.padding-bottom--l {
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.padding-left--none {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.padding-left--xs {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.padding-left--s {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.padding-left--m {
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.padding-left--l {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might lose the padding that you want for the columns. They end up sticking to each other. To prevent that, you could update the class as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-3 NoPaddingForChildren">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Id</label>
                    <input ng-model="ID" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Value</label>
                    <input ng-model="Val" class="form-control">
        </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding class:

```
.NoPaddingForChildren > div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.NoPaddingForChildren > div:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.NoPaddingForChildren > div:last-child {    
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you download bootstrap with the SASS files you will be able to edit the config file where there are a setting for the margin of the columns and then save it, in that way the SASS calculates the new width of the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Bootstrap Grid system and define your custom responsive grid.

change your default values for the following gutter width from `@grid-gutter-width = 30px` to `@grid-gutter-width = 0px`

(Gutter width is padding between columns. It gets divided in half for the left and right.)

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer to have control over every padding in every screen size so this css might be usefull to You guys :)

```
.nopadding-lg {
    padding-left: 0!important;
    padding-right: 0!important;
}
.nopadding-left-lg {padding-left: 0!important;}
.nopadding-right-lg {padding-right: 0!important;}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .nopadding-xs {
        padding-left: 0!important;
        padding-right: 0!important;
    }
    .nopadding-left-xs {padding-left: 0!important;}
    .nopadding-right-xs {padding-right: 0!important;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .nopadding-sm {
        padding-left: 0!important;
        padding-right: 0!important;
    }
    .nopadding-left-sm {padding-left: 0!important;}
    .nopadding-right-sm {padding-right: 0!important;}
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .nopadding-md {
        padding-left: 0!important;
        padding-right: 0!important;
    }
    .nopadding-left-md {padding-left: 0!important;}
    .nopadding-right-md {padding-right: 0!important;}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use fork

https://github.com/srghma/bootstrap-rubygem-without-gutter/commit/8e42c16dcc2f132af3489c2275dd7460b524d437

```
gem "bootstrap", github: "srghma/bootstrap-rubygem-without-gutter"
```

Comment: There must be a way to solve it in a simpler way, yo.