# Div Row padding issue using Twitter Bootstrap and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have a table constructed out of Bootstrapped divs. I have a nested row that I am using a slideToggle() to hide and view as the user clicks on the parent div.

The padding for the child div seems to be acting funny using Chrome. When I click on the parent div the child displays, when it finishes the animation it snaps back up about 15px.

I have a feeling it could be something with chrome as it doesn't have any issues in jsfiddle.

Here is a rundown of my code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row standardRow hoverdiv">

                    ITEM4

                <div class="row moreInfo hoverdiv">
                    <div class="col-md-12 moreInfo">
                            blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>


.standardRow {
       padding-bottom:10px;
       padding-top:10px;
       border-bottom:1px groove
    }

    .moreInfo {
        padding-top:10px;
    }
```

You can see my code at http://jsfiddle.net/FXBeL/4/. It appears to look fine in there, but not when I test the code in chrome.

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this structure for html. I think it will help u...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row standardRow hoverdiv">
      <div class="col-lg-12">ITEM4 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 moreInfo"> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```