# Bootstrap input-group removes padding from col-XX-X

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form that includes an input-group. I use the 'col'-classes of bootstrap to style it, but when this is combined with the 'input-group'-class, the padding of the columns are removed.

I would like the date and name input-field to be aligned.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/68afyjpy/1/) is my JSFiddle

HTML

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use special classes to remove padding see this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: do you use custom css? If so - just add the according rules so it would override Bootstrap. Other way is to customize your bootstrap.
Also if it is a one time case you can add the rules inline ( would not recommend but it's an option)

Comment: @DesignSnippet.com yes I could do that, but would Bootstrap not have a solution for this?

Comment: @MaksymStepanenko I don't use any custom css. I need it 5 times, so inline is possible, but preferably not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `input-group` class should not be combined with any other, as indicated in their examples (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! I looked at the website, but I must have missed the note.