# Bootstrap: 3x3 grid, featured image should be 2x2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, gallery

I am sorry but I am completely stumped on this one. I am trying to get my head around how to build the following:

I would like to create a simple responsive gallery consisting of a 3x3 grid where the featured image is larger than the other images and spans 2x2.

Not sure if I am making sense. But I have no idea how to put this together in bootstrap.

Here is the idea: http://imgur.com/0VNnbHi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Bootstrap grid system, you could essentially do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3hprmbrr/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 no-padding">
            <div class="featured-image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="little-image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="little-image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
            <div class="little-image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
            <div class="little-image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">
            <div class="little-image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.featured-image {
    height: 400px;
    border: 10px solid white;

}
.little-image {
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid white;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0 !important;   
}
```

The classes like `col-xs-8` define an element's width in percentages (`col-xs-8` means 66% of the page on extra-small viewports and up), and are used with multiples of 12.

Padding/borders are an issue with this approach, as columns also usually have [fixed padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3), which creates "gutters" between the columns. I've added a `.no-padding` class to help out with this.  As you can see in my example, it still doesn't line up great.

Check out the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) on the grid system for more details.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I do not use the css you provided, it lines up perfectly :)