# Make div grid bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been make grid using bootstrap width 100% but right and left has a padding.

How to make partition of this image [image] on grid using bootstrap width 100% ?

Comment: i think that's padding of `div class="row"`, should post the relevant code or wants us to keep guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate? [Remove padding from columns in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

you can just add a new class to the existing rows

`.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}`

or just add

`.row{
  padding:0!important;
}`

to your css to turn it off for all rows.

*edit* 
Also make sure you are using class `container-fluid` for your layout to be 100%

Answer (score 0):

By default "row"" class having padding left and padfing right.please remove padding and add "text-center" class to the div.