# Best approach to divide Bootstrap grid columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have divided my [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) grid columns following way.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12">B1</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Visual Layout of this code]

Please find below of visual layout of this code.

Is my approach of dividing grid columns correct or wrong?

Comment: rule of thumb: bootstrap columns should never be nested directly inside a column, you always need to create a row

Comment: I would recommend studying the [foundations of the Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always wrap your column inside a row to avoid any css break when resizing/or something like that

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">A </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">B
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">B1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">C </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code above seems to be missing the div container tag. Its there though wehn you edit the answer. So the code above is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You should add row divs for children inside B.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        A
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">B1</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
        C
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add an `row` div inside B for every line of columns inside: `b`, `b1.1, b1.2` and `b2.1, b2.2`. This should help.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        A
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class='row'>
                  <div class="col-md-12">B1</div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
        C
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">B1</div></div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
            </div>
            </div>
  </div>

Comment: I placed code for you, I thought my first version of answer was a little too less. You can check it there :)

Answer (score 2):

You should always wrap your columns inside the `row` for better layout without spacing in the columns or `clearfix` for layout with spacing:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="clearfix">
               <div class="col-md-12">B1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="clearfix">
                       <div class="col-md-8">B1.1</div>
                       <div class="col-md-4">B1.2</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="clearfix">
                   <div class="col-md-10">B2.1</div>
                   <div class="col-md-2">B2.2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might be interested to see this Q/A, [Remove padding from columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3).