# Bootstrap 3 grid not behaving as expected when resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The following code works fine at certain resolutions but when I squeeze the browser down, the `col-xs-1` gets pushed to the next line. This code is very plain and simple, I'm not sure what is wrong here.

It seems the `bootstrap` width percentages are off by a tiny amount.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
        8
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
        1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05fef33g/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is padding.

Bootstrap assumes you are using its layout configuration; its Navbar and other elements have default padding so everything is aligned. I fixed your example somewhat; on your fiddle I couldn't see bootstrap.js nor jquery.js so I wrote up a jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/komevecaho/edit?html,output

Also, this SO question may help clear things up: [Remove padding from columns in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3)