# A way to make Bootstrap col-xx no padding between the columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The `padding` defined in Bootstrap col-xx classes are sometimes wasting spaces on small screens, so I'd like to remove the padding by nesting col-xx with certain css settings like so:

```
<style>
div[class^=col-] > div[class^=col-] {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-4">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">b</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does my implemention look ok ? Are there any protential styling problems for nesting col-xx directly ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: You should also include `margin: 0`. and you can shorten padding like `padding: 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no problems, but i would not declare the 0 padding on the entire col-X, instead i would create a custom no-padding class, and apply the 0 padding to that class.

```
<style>
.no-padding{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">b</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its a good idea to not modify the style of boostrap core elements, because it might be confusing to other people working on the same code.