# Bootstrap 3 unwanted padding despites container-fluid class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap.
It always adds a padding left and right to my site. I use a "container-fluid" see this example:

```
...</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="top">
PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
</div>
</div>
```

or something like

```
...</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="top">
PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

or like this

```
...</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-12">
<div class="top">
PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

or

```
...</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="top">
PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The padding appaer always, no chance.

What is my fault?
I don't want to override with other CSS like here:

[Remove padding from columns in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: No, that don't solve the problem.

Comment: If removing the container doesn't solve the problem then you have another container somewhere that's causing this.

Comment: CSS of class top:
`.top {
  background:#000 url(bg_oben.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  height: 60vh;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow a structure:

```
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="anyclass">
          PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also define body and html style

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

To avoid gaps you can use BS class `row` which has negative margins by default:

```
row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;`
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this solution already (without define body and html style) and this don't work for me.

Comment: Enter post the comment... ):
Now I tried again with define body and html style, it won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own class, for example `.remove-padding` and overwrite bootstrap CSS.

```css
.remove-padding{
  padding: 0px !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid remove-padding">
  <div class="top">
    PAGE CONTENT WITH MORE DIVS
  </div>
</div>
```

Please be careful with use `!important`, I used because the code snippet in stackoverflow import external CSS after my CSS. If your styles are imported before bootstrap styles, you will not need to `!important` to overwrite Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: As I wrote above, I preffer a solution without add a new class. It must be done with bottstrap itself, or not?

Comment: Its only new class which reset padding, I think that is a simple and clear solution

Comment: That doesn't help me.
Once I change the code the black stripes right and left gone (the padding) but a horizontal scrollbar appears...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by myself. The padding comes from the `<div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-12">`.

Here the complete HTML Code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 remove-padding">
          <header>
            CONTENT
          </header>
       </div><!-- .col-md-12 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
    BODY...
 </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
```

Im adding the `remove-padding` class to disable the padding.
My css:

```
.remove-padding{
padding: 0px !important;
}
```

And the default bootstrap CSS:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Why adds bootstrap here padding and nothing removes it?
Im worried...