# How to fill these gap's b/w these two columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstraps gird and I get the gap b/w the columns:

```css
p {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Huge text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Huge text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is happening because columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Comment: Please do a bit research before posting a question on SO. Check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562903/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: each column `col` has a 15px paddings on right and left.

Answer (score 0):

This gutter is standard Bootstrap behaviour. An interesting and very useful snippet to override it is this:

```
.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
   padding-right:0;
   padding-left:0;
}
```

Used with:

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
```